# Compare 2 data frames with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the below dataframes and want to plot 2 weeks of data with ggplot.

```
df<-data.frame(
  Date=sample(seq(as.Date('2018-10-25'), as.Date('2018-11-20'), by = "day"), 100,replace = T),
  category1=sample(letters[1:6],100,replace = T),
  count=sample(1:1000,100,replace = T)
)
```

**Data Frame-1 (Last 7 Days)**

```
df1<-df%>%select(everything())%>%filter(Date < Sys.Date()-1 & Date>=Sys.Date()-8)%>%
  group_by(Date,category1)%>%summarise(Total=sum(count))
```

**Data Frame-2 (Last 8 days to 15 days)**

```
df2<-df%>%select(everything())%>%filter(Date < Sys.Date()-8 & Date>=Sys.Date()-15)%>%
  group_by(Date,category1)%>%summarise(Total=sum(count))
```

Plots :

```
ggplot(df1,aes(Date,Total,fill=category1))+geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "stack",width = 0.8,alpha=0.8)
```

[image: data frame 1]

```
ggplot(df2,aes(Date,Total,fill=category1))+geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "stack",width = 0.8,alpha=0.8)
```

[image: data frame 2]

Now how to plot the same content comparing the 2 plots ?
Any extra information if  required please let me know.

Comment: i want to compare first data frame result with second data frame result like TOTAL count needs to be compare with one week to another week

Comment: to know how the progress of total from one week to last week data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using facets, where I show each date of the last week as a facet, with the # of whole weeks prior on the x axis of each facet.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(days_old = (as.Date("2018-11-20") - Date) / lubridate::ddays(1),
         weeks_ago = days_old %/% 7,
         adj_to_this_week = as.Date("2018-11-20") - days_old %% 7) %>%
  group_by(adj_to_this_week, weeks_ago, category1) %>% 
  summarise(Total=sum(count))


ggplot(df1 %>%
         filter(weeks_ago <= 1) %>%
         mutate(nice_dates = format(adj_to_this_week, "%b %d") %>% 
                             fct_reorder(adj_to_this_wk)), 
       aes(-weeks_ago, Total,fill=category1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "stack",width = 0.8,alpha=0.8) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = -1:0, labels = c("LW", "TW")) +
  facet_wrap(~nice_dates, nrow = 1) +
  labs(title = "Last week (LW) vs. This week (TW)", x ="") +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Sample data:

```
set.seed(42)
df<-data.frame(
  Date=sample(seq(as.Date('2018-10-25'), as.Date('2018-11-20'), by = "day"), 100,replace = T),
  category1=sample(letters[1:6],100,replace = T),
  count=sample(1:1000,100,replace = T)
)
```

Comment: looks good and i have one doubt...we are comparing the 2 different date ranges but facet was used with another dates...can u please clarify how can we use dates  in facet?

Comment: Date is expressed here alternatively, as the number of whole weeks ago (`weeks_ago`), and the day of this week it would align with (`adj_to_this_wk`). You can facet to `adj_to_this_wk` but then it would be formatted like "2018-11-14." To make it prettier, I made a formatted version called `nice_dates`, and made that a factor ordered by dates. Then it will show up as a string, but sorted chronologically instead of alphabetically.

Comment: superb...thanks for the response and trying with real time usage data